# Fix blurry text in a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, ocr

I have a PDF containing both text and images. Images are ok, but the text is blurry, with a "pixelated" pattern, very difficult to read. If I copy-paste the text from Adobe Acrobat to another app, such as Microsoft Word, the text is perfectly fine with no errors. Also, when I zoom in/zoom out the PDF in Acrobat, there is a split second (I think because Acrobat is reloading the page) in which I can see the text defined and sharp. So I think Acrobat can actually recognize the text but somehow it doesn't manage to display it properly.

Is there a way I can fix the PDF?

Comment: How does it look in another PDF viewer, e.g., Sumatra PDF, https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader ? If that's OK, then the issue is settings within the Adobe *viewer*; if not, the PDF has been badly made.